# How to handle select change using material-ui in reactjs and Mongodb

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have this code that updates the input fields

```
    const handleInputChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target
        setUser({ ...user, [name]: value })
    }
```

I want to approach the same idea but with `Select` component

My select component from the registration page:

```
        <Select
          id="framework"
          value={FrameworkValue}
          onChange={handleChange}
          fullWidth
          label="Framework"
          margin="normal"
        >
        <MenuItem value={'Information Security'}>Information Security</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={'Health'}>Health</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={'Quality Management'}>Quality Management</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={'Financial'}>Financial</MenuItem>
        </Select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `name` and `value` props to `Select` component like below.

```
    <Select
      ...
      value={user.framework}
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      ...
      ...
      name="framework"
    >
    <MenuItem value={'Information Security'}>Information Security</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={'Health'}>Health</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={'Quality Management'}>Quality Management</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={'Financial'}>Financial</MenuItem>
    </Select>
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicselect-material-demo-forked-b73e2?file=/demo.js)

Comment: @JHS99, check this out !!